# How can I convert installdate to a different format?

Tags: string, date, cmd, product, wmic

I am trying to run this command on cmd:

```
wmic:root\cli>/node:IPAddress product get name, version, vendor, installdate
```

IPAddress can be replaced with whatever address or hostname is desired.

The command does not give me any errors, however, it gives me installdate in `MMMMYYDD` form (for example, `20170801` instead of something simple like `01-Aug-2017` or `2017/08/01`). I have tried to look for solutions online, but they're usually talking about system installations instead of product installations.

I know that installdate is a string, so this is more a question of how should I convert this string into a date. I tried using '+%Y%m%d' after the installdate, but it gave me an error: Invalid GET Expression.

Comment: That is not avalid command you could execute in cmd. In general to process the output of another command you need a [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: The command comes after wmic:root\cli>

Comment: As a batcher I  never did use the interactive variant.

Comment: You cannot force the `wmic` console to change the returned date format. By the way: what's wrong with `YYYYMMDD` format?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, I was just wondering if there was a way to show it so that it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PowerShell, it is not too difficult. You can control the format you want in the `ToString` method.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Product |
    Select-Object -Property @{n='Name';e={$_.Name}}, @{n='Date';e={([datetime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate,'yyyyMMdd', $null)).ToString('dd-MMM-yyyy')}}
```